# Is there a specific MySQL grant permission to allow user to create and drop other users?

Tags: mysql, user-permissions

I was looking through the MySQL documentation for information on how to grant a user the ability to create and drop other users. The examples given are for creating and dropping databases and tables.

Does the GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES permission assigned to a user also implicitly mean that they can create and drop other users? If so, is there any other GRANT privilege that allows this without automatically making the user a superuser? Or would the process be first making them a superuser and then revoking specific permissions?

Comment: There is a `CREATE USER` privilege. See details [here in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: Thanks, but CREATE USER is a command to create the user vs. a privilege/permission assigned to the user. I'm looking for a way to grant either the newly created user or existing user with the permission to create other users.

Comment: From the documentation: "The CREATE USER privilege enables use of ALTER USER, CREATE USER, DROP USER, RENAME USER, and REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES.". So read the section for [`ALTER USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html) for the correct syntax. Once a User has that privilege he can as stated create, alter, drop and rename users. Don't forget to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`. At least root has that privilege out of the box. You can use that user to give it to another user and so on.

Comment: Ah, okay. So, if I'm creating a new user, it would just be a part of the `GRANT` section: `CREATE USER '<user>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>' GRANT CREATE USER ON testdb.* TO '<user>'@'%'`.  Thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To use DROP USER, you must have the global CREATE USER privilege or the DELETE privilege for the mysql database.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-user.html
>
> To use the first REVOKE syntax, you must have the GRANT OPTION privilege, and you must have the privileges that you are revoking.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html

The `GRANT OPTION` privilege is not part of `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ...`.  It has to be specified at the end of the `GRANT` statement, `... WITH GRANT OPTION`.  This privilege allows a user possessing it to grant any privileges that the user possesses... to other users.  Or to revoke them.  (You can't grant a privilege that you, yourself, lack... or revoke one, as noted above.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm working on a tool that incorporates both PostgreSQL and MySQL functionalities and still learning each's peculiarities. PostgreSQL seems so much more straightforward in granting permissions. I'm starting to see why so many people prefer PostgreSQL.

Comment: MySQL is very much a product of evolution, while PostgreSQL *could* be argued to be a product of more deliberate design.  The thing you have to watch out for with Postgres is the rabid fanboys.  MySQL is an excellent platform, and the innovations of MariaDB and Percona have made significant contributions.